# MediaPlayer didnt update file Duration

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming, duration, internet-radio

I open a connection to download a stream to a file on the sdcard after writing some bytes I start the MediaPlayer to play the File 
my problem is that  MediaPlayer read just the Duratio calculated in  phase of 
preparation

Comment: Could you add some code to show us exactly how it is working? MediaPlayer is a tricky beast sometimes and seeing the actual code is often helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct behavior. When you use the MediaPlayer for playing local files, the file is scanned once when the MediaPlayer is initialized and no further scanning will be started. The MediaPlayer does not know that you'll append more data to the file. One solution will be to use the MediaPlayer to stream the file directly over the network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer 
I download the stream  to file in order to record some part of it Later.
is there a way to make MediaPlayer update the new duration of file ??
The Iphone player update the duration every second

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by temporarily opening the same file in a new media player, get the duration and release it again. In order to save system resources this should only be done periodically, say every 5th second, and only if the file has actually changed.

```
public boolean fileSizeHasChanged() {
    long currentFileSize = new File(mCurrentMediaFile).length();
    if (currentFileSize == mLastFileSize)
        return false;
    mLastFileSize = currentFileSize;
    return true;
}

public int getDuration() {
    long currentDurationCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentDurationCheck - mLastDurationCheck < 5000)
        return mDuration;
    mLastDurationCheck = currentDurationCheck;

    if (!fileSizeHasChanged())
        return mDuration;

    // mp is the main media player actual playing, mp2 is the auxillary one
    MediaPlayer mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mp2.setDataSource(mCurrentMediaFile);
        mp2.prepare();
        mDuration = mp2.getDuration();
        mp2.release();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mDuration;
}
```